# MySQL: group by and nearest integer

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

**location:**

```
userId |  zip  | 
----------------
   1   | 12383 |
   1   | 10253 |
   2   | 10523 |
   2   | 14856 |
   2   | 10251 |
   3   |  NULL |
```

For a given integer X, I want to sort the user according to who has a integer in column `zip` that is closest to X, together with the corresponding number of `zip`. If the user has value `NULL` in field `zip` then he should be shown at the end.

Example: 
 For X = 5000, I would like to get the output

```
userId |  zip  | 
----------------
   2   | 10251 |
   1   | 10253 |
   3   |  NULL |
```

I managed to get the userId's correctly sorted with:

```
SELECT userId, MIN(ABS(3-zip)) as dist FROM location GROUP BY userId Order by -dist DESC
```

producing the table

```
userId |  dist  | 
-----------------
   2   |  5251  |
   1   |  5253  |
   3   |  NULL  |
```

but how can I also get the nearest zip code?

Comment: It isn't clear how two zip codes are "close" to each other in your example.  What is the meaning of `X = 3` ?  Also, a small difference between two zip codes does not necessarily imply that the two areas represented by those zip codes are actually close (although there probably is a correlation).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I consider a zip code simply as an integer. Maybe I should edit my question. But here the meaning is which zipcode is closest to the value 3

Comment: This is really unclear.

Comment: @Strawberry no, because then userId `3` would be closer to `X`

Comment: @Strawberry what is unclear?

Comment: @Strawberry It's unclear because he is using the value `3` as a zip code, when it really looks like a `userId`.  Just replace `3` with something like `90210` and it won't look as strange.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, I get that. But this only works in  vertical city (or really, really narrow) city !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry It doesn't really "work" at all.  The zip codes should be matched to a latitude and longitude and distance determined this way, or something similar.  But in any case I gave an answer below.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. Yes your right, I am not looking for the nearest zip code in geographical sense but simply the closest number. I changed X to a larger number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.userId,
       t1.zip
FROM location t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userId, MIN(ABS(3-zip)) AS dist
    FROM location
    GROUP BY userId
) t2
    ON t1.userId = t2.userId AND
       (ABS(3 - t1.zip) = t2.dist OR t2.dist IS NULL)   -- pay careful attention here
ORDER BY -t2.dist DESC                                  -- join on the absolute difference
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

There are a few tricks in this query:

- Joining on `ABS(# - zip)` ensures that we choose the closest zip, regardless of whether it is higher or lower
- The `t2.dist IS NULL` condition in the join includes a user who has a `NULL` zip code
- Using `ORDER BY -t2.dist DESC` sorts the zip codes in *ascending* order, but also places `NULL` at the *end* of the result set.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just noticed that  in order to integrate also the NULL values you need to change the ON condition to `ON t1.userId = t2.userId AND (ABS(3 - t1.zip) = t2.dist or t2.dist is null)` . Further, if the NULL values should be sorted last, the one needs to change `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY -t2.dist DESC`.

Comment: This sounds like you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead, since `t2.userId` will never be `NULL` in the above query.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If I use your above query for the table **location** above, then I only get the first two rows `[2 | 10251]` and `[1 | 10253 ]`,  the row  `[3 | null]` is missing. I think the problem is that `(ABS(3 - t1.zip) = t2.dist` is not true when t1.zip = Null and t2.dist=null, since comparison with null never returns true or false, but always null. I think my solution from my comment is valid. I am not sure how you could accomplish that with a left join instead.

Comment: In addition, in the table **location** every userId may appear multiple times, but in my resulting table I only want that each userId appears once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT userId, ABS(MIN(ABS(zip-3)) + IF(zip - 3 >= 0, 3, -3)) as dist
FROM location
GROUP BY userId
Order by ABS(MIN(ABS(zip-3)) + IF(zip - 3 >= 0, 3, -3)) IS NOT NULL DESC, userId DESC
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3507f/1)

***Edited:***

```
SELECT userId, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(zip ORDER BY ABS(zip - 3)), ',', 1) as dist
FROM location
GROUP BY userId
Order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(zip ORDER BY ABS(zip - 3)), ',', 1) IS NOT NULL DESC, userId DESC
```

[<kbd>New solution demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3507f/5)

Comment: X is dynamic input. What if some zip are greater and some are smaller then X?

Comment: Not matter it's greater or smaller, if it just some digit numbers, it alway has an order, doesn't it? @Adam

Comment: If zip has values `1` and `4` in the database, then your code would compute that 1 is closer to 3 then 4 is to 3 and thats not true. I cannot dismiss `ABS()`here.

Comment: Wow awesome! Nice solution and doesnt need a JOIn! THANK YOU

Comment: @Adam I've even commented yet. :-D

Comment: Your SQL is not exactly working as I needed it, but your idea was great. There is no need to use ABS twice and your order by is acutally not working (ZIP code 4 is closer to 3 then 10251 to 3, therefore 4 should be first). I think the SQL should be changed to `SELECT userId, MIN(ABS(zip-3)) + IF(zip - 3 >= 0, 3, -3) as zip
FROM location
GROUP BY userId
Order by -MIN(ABS(zip-3))  DESC`

Comment: No actually is should be  `SELECT userId, MIN(ABS(zip-3)) + IF(zip - 3 >= 0, 3, -3 + 2 * zip) as zip
FROM location
GROUP BY userId
Order by -MIN(ABS(zip-3))  DESC` sorry for spam

Comment: @Adam I've updated my answer, please check it again please.

Comment: It seems to me that your new solution demo still computes that |10251 - 3 | < | 4 - 3 | ?

Comment: @Adam No, do you see the demo?